# Canvas path memory allocation.

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a loop that gets called through a window.setInterval every 30 millsec.

it looks like this:

```
var loop = function (w, t){
    for( i=0; i<w; i++){
        value= something*t;
        ctx.strokeStyle="rgba(" + Math.floor(color[0]*value) + "," + Math.floor(color[1]*value) + "," + Math.floor(color[2]*value) + "," + 255 + ")";
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(i ,0);
        ctx.lineTo(i ,h);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

var color =[0,0,0];
var myLoop=window.setInterval(function(){
     loop(width, time);
}, 30);
```

For reference w is usually ~ 1000-1500

When I run this on a computer I have no problems at all. However, running on a device with less memory the program runs very slowly (ie. it draws to the canvas slowly).

I figure I have some memory leak somewhere, but I don't see where.

Alternatively, I could be crazy and allocating 1000 canvas paths is way too many. But I can't find an explanation of how the canvas drawing methods allocate memory.

Any hints?

Comment: `i` is not declared, that could be an issue.

Comment: I tried that. Seems to be of minimal difference. Thanks though!

Comment: You're trying to paint the whole canvas line-by-line? Why don't you use `fillRect()`?

Comment: @Bergi, Yes I am attempting to paint it line-by-line. I don't use fillRect() because in the implementation, each line is a different fill style.

Here you can see the result:
http://www.airhenig.com/zebrafish/other.html

Comment: Looks like you could move the strokeStyle generation out of the loop, or at least some of it. Probably also only need to set line width once. You should seriously consider moving to `setTimeout` and not using `setInterval`; what happens if the interval is shorter than the function's execution?

Comment: Oops, right. Maybe you should try painting the `imageData`?

Comment: Paul, good point about the setTimeout function rather than setInterval. I just never have had a problem before of the function execution exceeding the interval time.

Bergi, changing imageData, was my next goto. I just could not figure out why this method should not work. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you have given here there are several issues:

```
i, h, time, something
```

are not defined. All variables that are not defined with `var` makes the `window` object dirty. Always declare all variables explicitly.

You don't need to use `rgba` when alpha channel = 255, just use `rgb`.

You can use `fillStyle` instead so you can use fillRect instead - this will do the same as moveTo + lineTo but this one is more semantic:

```
ctx.fillRect(i, 0, i + 1 , h);
```

And there is no need to use `closePath()` here as you are only drawing a line (nothing to close it with - it will just create another line on top of itself going from last point back to start so you are basically stroking double unless this is optimized for internally by the browser).

Use `requestAnimationFrame` (rAF) instead of `setInterval`. With the latter you risk stacking call and it doesn't sync to monitor vblank as rAF does (and rAF is more efficient).. In worst case use `setTimeout` instead.

You can also use `value|0` instead of `Math.floor`.

**Update** - I forgot to also mention that *Garbage Collection* will have difficulties kicking in while you're in a busy loop. So for mobile devices optimizations become more important as the CPU on those is not so capable as does on a desktop computer - optimized code leave some time to breath so-to-speak.

Comment: i, h, time, and something all all officially declared. I just posted a shortened version. I will make the other changes. Thanks!

Comment: I made the first changes, like fillrect(). They honestly did not do much. But switching over to requestAnimationFrame really did the trick! Thanks so much!

Comment: @dogofsteel yeah, the fillRect was more semantics as I stated. rAF is your friend however :)

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks again.